# Problem with cross compiling libc.so.6 for armhf - inconsistent architectures

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, libc

I am cross-compiling a go (golang) program to armhf. The program compiles successfully, but when I try to run it on an ARM board, it crashes with 'Illegal instruction' error.

Chasing down the problem, I am almost sure this is due to fact that glib.so.6 has inconsistent architecture.

Facts:
Host: ubuntu 18 (bionic), amd64
GCC: gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 
I am using multiarch (armhf)

My Cortex-a5 ARM processor:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 262.96
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp vfpv3 vfpv3d16 tls vfpv4 <br>
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc05
CPU revision    : 1
<br>
Hardware        : SAMA5D3X-EK
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000
```

All my armhf shared libraries have the following architecture:

```
$ readelf -A /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.27.so
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_rounding: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```

However, the armhf libc.so.6 is:

```
$ readelf -A /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.27.so 
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3
  Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_rounding: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_user_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```

If I understand things correctly, this is wrong, as my processor does not support neon.

An old version of libc.so.6 on the ARM board looks as follows:

```
$ readelf -A /media/marek/sd/board/libc.so.6 
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: Deprecated
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed
```

Which looks consistent with the rest.

I wrote a trivial hello world program, and it crashes, too. But when I replace the armhf libc.so.6 with the old version on the board, it runs OK. However, I need a new version of libc (>= 2.25). Thus, it looks like it is sufficient to cross compile it from sources.

I am using configure with the following options:
../configure arm-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=`pwd` CFLAGS='-march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -g -O2 -w' LDFLAGS='-march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -g -w'

(also tried without LDFLAGS). All static libraries have the desired architecture but libc.so still has the wrong one (as above) - VFPv3 and NEONv1 are set). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you could try adding a -mfloat-abi=softfp option to CFLAGS along with -mfpu=vfpv3-d16, so the neon floating point options get ignored, and might get you further

Comment: Unfortunately, this produces a compile error: In file included from ../sysdeps/gnu/unwind-resume.c:22:0:
/home/marek/libs/glibc/glibc-2.29/build/gnu/lib-names.h:8:11: fatal error: gnu/lib-names-soft.h: No such file or directory
 # include <gnu/lib-names-soft.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Comment: Is there an error in the .configure step ? Also, can you run .configure with different options like ./configure --host=x86_64 --target=armv7a --build=armv7. Anyway it seems the cross compile libraries are the worng ones, so you may need to install them

Comment: Thank you for you help. I have checked the architecture of all *.o files and only two of them have NEON set: memchr_neon.o and memcpy_neon.o. Perhaps this is the reason the final library has it set as well? How could I get rid of these files during linking? Or maybe the problem lies somewhere else and I am just go round and round?

Comment: I am not sure what is going on but apparently for *.S files the arm options are missing. The compiler reports errors (that a given ASM instruction is not supported in arm mode) but if I add the flags manually to the command, the file compiles. Are there any specific options for configure for .S files?

Comment: No, there is no error in configure. Considering libraries and the compiler, I installed them using standard mechanism, apt-get install. I will try configure with other options on Monday. Thank you.

Comment: OK, solved. The problem was that by default the compiler inserts a path to ld-linux-armhf to executable and an incorrect one was used during application launch (the embedded system uses old libraries) and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in itself was not sufficient. After changing this path to the correct one everything is ok. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well done to you, you solved it yourself ! Cross compiling toolchains can sometimes get quite messy !